# Return a result value from shell script for tests in Docker container to Jenkins CI

Tags: bash, shell, docker, jenkins, nightwatch.js

I want to use `Jenkins CI` to execute my automated end2end tests. My tests are running with `Nightwatch.js`. I want to run my automated tests in a self created docker container via a shell script. This shell script runs on local machine perfect, but if I start this shell script in `Jenkins CI` the shell script has to return a value, if the tests pass or fail. If they pass the Jenkins job has to pass too. And when the tests in Docker container fail then the Jenkins job has to fail, too.

Here is my current shell script:

```
#run the end2end tests headless in docker container from local with remote repository
#parameter: $1 folder on local machine to copy in project sources (with cucumber reports after test execution)
#              (IMPORTANT: You have to ensure that the given folder path is in the file sharing paths in Docker configuration!!!)
#           $2 git url with credentials to GitLab repo (e.g. https://<username>:<password>@gitlab.com/hrsinnolab/e2e-web-tests.git)
#           $3 defined the running browser (scipts in package.json)
#           $4 branch to run the tests against (optionally / if empty then the 'master' is used for tests as default)
#examples:
# run the tests with chrome against the branch 'NIKITA-1234'
#./runTestsLocal /Users/me/e2e-tests/reports/ https://me:mypassword@gitlab.com/hrsinnolab/e2e-web-tests.git test-chrome NIKITA-1234
# run the tests with firefox against the default 'master'
#./runTestsLocal /Users/me/e2e-tests/reports/ https://me:mypassword@gitlab.com/hrsinnolab/e2e-web-tests.git test-firefox
docker_image=grme/nightwatch-chrome-firefox:0.0.2
echo "------ stop all Docker containers ------" \
&& (docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) || echo "------ all Docker containers are still stopped ------") \
&& echo "------ remove all Docker containers ------" \
&& (docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || echo "------ all Docker containers are still removed ------") \
&& echo "------ pull Docker image '"$docker_image"' from Docker Cloud ------" \
&& docker pull "$docker_image" \
&& echo "------ start Docker container from image ------" \
&& docker run -d -t -i -v $1:/my_tests/ "$docker_image" /bin/bash \
&& echo "------ execute end2end tests on Docker container ------" \
&& docker exec -it $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c \
  "rm -Rf /my_tests/project \
  && git clone $2 /my_tests/project \
  && cd /my_tests/project \
  && git checkout $4 \
  && npm install \
  && npm install -y nightwatch-cucumber@7.1.10 \
  && npm install -y chromedriver@2.30.1 \
  && npm install -y geckodriver@1.7.1 \
  && npm install -y cucumber-html-reporter@2.0.3 \
  && npm install -y multiple-cucumber-html-reporter@0.2.0 \
  && xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1600x1200x24' npm run $3" \
&& echo "------ cleanup all temporary files ------" \
&& rm -Rf $1/project/tmp-* \
&& rm -Rf $1/project/.com.google* \
&& echo "------ stop all Docker containers again ------" \
&& (docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) || echo "------ all Docker containers are still stopped ------") \
&& echo "------ remove all Docker containers again ------" \
&& (docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || echo "------ all Docker containers are still removed ------")
```

How can I return a value to give the Jenkins job an information about the test status? I know it should be difficult, because I execute a shell script which starts Docker container and executes the tests within this Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you might need from my answer below could be:
`exit $?`
`$?`gives you the return value of your previous command/script

Full Answer:
I have a similar setup how I deal with executing the nightwatch tests in an docker container inside jenkins:

```
RC=0
docker exec -i ${DOCKER_NIGHTWATCH} node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --suiteRetries 1 || RC=$?
exit $RC
```

Container is obviously started beforehand with `-d` and `sleep`.

But actually I don't think it is a good practice to relay on an exit code from a shell script when executing the tests. What I also did for this job is, that I started the container with `-v ${WORKSPACE}/reports:/nightwatch/reports` argument and I added a Post-build Action `Publish JUnit test result report` and specified the reports folder to be included. This helps you getting better information about yours system health.

Hope that helps you! :)